# composer network start is not working v 0.19

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am using fabric 1.1.0 and composer 0.19

I have set up a google cloud instance. composer network start command either throws REQUEST_TIMEOUT or below exception.

018-05-21 08:10:04.599 UTC [util] DockerBuild -> DEBU 4b8 Attempting build with image hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:x86_64-1.1.0
2018-05-21 08:10:58.039 UTC [chaincode-platform] func1 -> ERRO 4b9 Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm WARN notice [SECURITY] stringstream has 1 moderate vulnerability. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=stringstream&version=0.0.6 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.9: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated buildmail@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.10: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] debug has 1 low vulnerability. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=debug&version=2.6.2 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.

Any help is much appreciated as i am clueless.
I am just trying to run single peer to start my sample app.

Note: Do you think running a server with 600 MB RAM would cause this

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to provide more detail on your question - with version info etc as shown here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#issue
2. You will most certainly have memory issues - you need a recommended minimum of 4Gb - and strictly follow the minimum prerequisite levels / versions shown here ->   https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html
3. Pay particular attention to the supporter Operating systems and versions (above) and the Node / npm / python versions.
4. Once you have your node, npm, docker and actual minimum spec (memory in Gbs, disk etc) in place, would you then go on and install Composer and then I would recommend trying to do the Developer tutorial - eg here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial

Comment: Thanks but i am able to install but unable to start

Answer (score 0):

Do you really mean 600MB of RAM?  If so then I would be surprised if the Fabric even runs.  Perhaps you mean 6000MB (6GB) which is fine for a development Fabric.

The longer error you show is for the failure to build the Chaincode Docker Image, but the details of that failure are only a set of npm Warnings.  There should be additional error messages in the Peer docker container.

If it is a genuine timeout, this [section in the Composer Knowledge Wiki](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#startissues) provides details of how to address that.

Comment: Thanks. I am also surprised that there are only warnings. I have already tried CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=1200s. It's not working. Is there any other way of debugging this. Even with composer playground i faced both these issues. Sometimes time out and sometimes error

Comment: one more line i get is > x509@0.3.3 install /chaincode/output/node_modules/x509
> node-gyp rebuild


"
error starting container

Comment: Solved.. was memory issue only.. upgraded the instance to about 4gb and it worked

Answer (score 0):

It was memory issue only. Upgraded to 4gb and it worked